# cronjob to run once while monitor a directory

Tags: shell, cron

I have a script which runs by a conjob upon receiving a file.

a=$(find /home/cassandra -type f -name "*.tar.gz" | wc -l); if [[ $a -gt 0 ]]; then python monitor.py ;fi

this script run continuously and execute monitor.py

I WANT shell script to run the monitor.py only upon receiving the tar.gz file.

Answer (score 0):

Does your monitor.py take a tgz file as its argument?

If it does, I would simplify your command and call monitor.py from the find.

```
find /home/cassandra -type f -name "*.tar.gz" -exec python monitor.py {} \;
```

The {} in the find command gets replaced with the file that was found. the \; ends the command string. The command in your exec gets called once for each file found.

If you wanted to pass all the files that were found by find to a command once, you can use xargs.

Comment: my script monitor.py don't take any file as a parameter.

Comment: Then you'll need to update your python script to take the file as an argument. It'll be in sys.argv[1].